Traer información privada del usuario con la api de mercado libre
cómo están?
Estoy siguiendo los pasos de la documentación de Mercado Libre para usar su API, pero cuando hago la llamada en Postman para traer la información privada del usuario, me trae la información pública solamente.
Adjunto una captura de pantalla:


desde la cuenta de ese usuario, debes dar autorizacion a tu APP. estoy desarrollando tambien! pero cuando entro en el DEVCENTER desde la cuenta de otro usuario, da error temporal. la pagina dice q intente mas tarde! prueba tu a ver si lo logras!
